# Apollo watchQuery method ignores passed variables

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-angular

I'm using angular-apollo lib to call backend graphql. I want to reuse my queries generated by `gql` function. It means I need to use `variables`, but when I write query like this:

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<MyQuery>({
          query: gql`
            {
              bar(id: $foo) {
                id
            }
          `,
          variables: {
            $foo: 'bar',
          },
        }).valueChanges
```

I'm getting not replaced placeholder `$foo` on the server-side:

```
...  WARN 16956 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] graphql.GraphQL                          : Query failed to validate : '{
  bar(id: $foo) {
    id
```

I'm using following apollo npm packages:

```
    "apollo-angular": "^1.7.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.8.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-apollo-angular-app-fyykeq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexchange-rates%2Fexchange-rates.component.ts

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Variables must be declared in the operation definition before they are used as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329598/apollo-client-variable-is-not-defined-received-status-code-400/54332801#54332801). Additionally, even though the variable name is prefixed with a `$` inside the GraphQL document, it should be passed in without it in Apollo (i.e. `foo: 'bar'`).

Comment: just a note: Approach what I use initially is work for update store:
`store.readQuery<...>({query: myQuery, variables: {id: this.id}});`